# position of TextView and ImageView in LinearLayout

Tags: android, textview, position, imageview, android-linearlayout

how do i make the position of TextView in the left of LinearLayout and ImageView in the right of LinearLayout

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        >
        <TextView  
            android:id="@+id/formulaTextKite"
            android:text="@string/formulasAreasKite"
            style="@style/stripFormulasTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />  
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/picAreaKite"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
            android:src="@drawable/areakite"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
```

thanks 
Itzik

Answer (score 2):

Its better to use RelativeLayout Like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        >
        <TextView  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:id="@+id/formulaTextKite"
            android:text="testing"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />  
        <ImageView android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:id="@+id/picAreaKite"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
            android:src="@drawable/icon"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
<LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:weightSum="3"
        > 
        <TextView   
            android:id="@+id/formulaTextKite" 
            android:text="@string/formulasAreasKite" 
            style="@style/stripFormulasTextView" 
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            />   
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"              //to keep anything in bettween
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"    //if dont need then take weightSum =2 not 3
            android:layout_weight="1">                 
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/picAreaKite" 
            android:layout_width="0dp" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/areakite" 
            /> 
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use layout_gravity

for textView use layout_gravity = "left"

and for imageView use layout_gravity = "right"

and also make your linear layout orientation vertical , for this to work.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

I used the Following xml arrangement and it worked:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:weightSum="3"
    > 
 <ImageView 
        android:id="@bbm" 
        android:layout_width="0dp" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/bbm" 
        /> 

<TextView  
        android:id="@+id/formulaTextKite"
        android:text="@string/formulasAreasKite"
        style="@style/stripFormulasTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />  



</LinearLayout>
```